# One video variant on MPEG DASH generated with AWS MediaConverter

Tags: video, aws-media-convert, shaka, adaptive-bitrate

I've produced an.MDP using MediaConverter, which has the following video streams

```
<AdaptationSet mimeType="video/mp4" frameRate="30/1" segmentAlignment="true" subsegmentAlignment="true" startWithSAP="1" subsegmentStartsWithSAP="1" bitstreamSwitching="false">
  <Representation id="1" width="3840" height="1920" bandwidth="67300000" codecs="avc1.4d4033">
    <BaseURL>index3.3840.1920.cmfv</BaseURL>
    <SegmentBase indexRange="764-1091">
      <Initialization range="0-763"/>
    </SegmentBase>
  </Representation>
  <Representation id="2" width="3840" height="1920" bandwidth="67300000" codecs="avc1.4d4033">
    <BaseURL>index5.3840.1920.cmfv</BaseURL>
    <SegmentBase indexRange="764-1091">
      <Initialization range="0-763"/>
    </SegmentBase>
  </Representation>
  <Representation id="3" width="3840" height="1920" bandwidth="67300000" codecs="avc1.4d4033">
    <BaseURL>index7.3840.1920.cmfv</BaseURL>
    <SegmentBase indexRange="764-1091">
      <Initialization range="0-763"/>
    </SegmentBase>
  </Representation>
  <Representation id="4" width="3840" height="1920" bandwidth="67300000" codecs="avc1.4d4033">
    <BaseURL>index9.3840.1920.cmfv</BaseURL>
    <SegmentBase indexRange="764-1091">
      <Initialization range="0-763"/>
    </SegmentBase>
  </Representation>
</AdaptationSet>
<AdaptationSet mimeType="audio/mp4" lang="und" segmentAlignment="0">
  <Representation id="5" bandwidth="96000" audioSamplingRate="48000" codecs="mp4a.40.2">
    <BaseURL>indexaudio.cmfa</BaseURL>
    <SegmentBase indexRange="658-985">
      <Initialization range="0-657"/>
    </SegmentBase>
  </Representation>
</AdaptationSet>
```

This was produced with the files with the following settings

```
  new VideoCodecSettings()
                            .withCodec(VideoCodec.H_264)
                            .withH264Settings(
                                new H264Settings()
                                    .withCodecLevel(H264CodecLevel.LEVEL_4_2)
                                    .withMaxBitrate(maxBitRate)
                                    .withRateControlMode("QVBR")
                                    .withQvbrSettings(new H264QvbrSettings()
                                        .withQvbrQualityLevel(quality)
                                    ).withSceneChangeDetect("TRANSITION_DETECTION")
                                )
                        )
```

When I play it Shaka Player - it only detects a single available variant and will only play the initial stream.

[image]

The Shaka player has default configurations but ABR is enabled.

Is this because all the bandwidths are the same?

I've configured with QVBR is that not the best way?

Answer (score 0):

That's correct, you must have CBR at different bitrates for the player to distinguish between the variants.